Setting breakpoint properties in Xilinx SDK
I am using the XSCT console (I MUST USE IT) for Xilinx SDK 2018.3 to add a watchpoint. I want to specify the Range property, which I can do using the GUI. So far I haven't been able to set this property using bpadd, I guess you use the -properties flag to do it, but there is no documentation for what are the available options.
This guy had the same question and no one answered: https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006hpNZ5SAM/advanced-breakpoint-options?language=en_US
I tried several iterations of: bpadd -addr 0xffff7eef -mode 0x1 -properties {range True units 1}
And got:
enter image description here
